# Is it secure to store my mysql password in a const std::string?

Tags: passwords, c++, mariadb

I am implementing a C++ server with a mariadb backend. I have to access my database and I do so using the mariadbpp (its c++ connector). Though I can use mysql_config_editor and store the passwords in an (encrypted) .cnf file, mariadbpp's API needs a password. This is how I am using it:

```
mariadb::account_ref acc = mariadb::account::create("localhost", "order", "<password>", "Orders");
```

The database is configured to only be accessible from localhost. Is putting the password in .cpp source file okay from security perspective?

Comment: Related: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/79717/165253

Comment: Note that storing the password in a const std::string at runtime is independent of hardcoding it in the program's source code. It's only the latter that's a bad idea.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you said @JosephSible . Do you mean storing the password in const std::string from a file, (at run time) is the same as hardcoding it. Just the latter is a really bad idea coz the hacker can analyze the binary and figure that out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hardcoding of secrets is never a good idea.**

Use a configuration file, to read from. This way you will be able to swiftly change the password if required and prevent the password from leaking through version control or binary analysis.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to do that in Mariadbpp?

Comment: I'm not familiar with mariadbpp, and cannot tell whether it offers built-in functionality for this, but your C++ binary could easily parse a configuration file, store the password from there in a variable and later use the variable to connect to the database.

Comment: Ya. Thats a good idea. How could I forget that

Answer (score 1):

No, anyone can execute the "Strings.exe" program on a compiled program to reveal any hard coded strings.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).